# Using defined variable in Each block with Svelte

Tags: svelte

I'm having a little trouble with updating variables using nested files. My expectation is that when the checkmark is `checked`, the variable `switchTouch` is updated. I'm clearly doing something incorrectly as this isn't the case. Any pointers would be welcomed:

```
<script>
    import Control from './Control.svelte'
    
    let switchTouch = false
    let switchScreen = true
    
     let controls = [
    { id: 1, title: 'Touch Targets', checked: switchTouch },
    { id: 2, title: 'Screen Reader', checked: switchScreen }
  ];
    
$: console.log(switchTouch)

</script>

{#each controls as control}
<Control title={control.title} bind:value={control.checked} />          
{/each}
```

The [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/7513779d030448ffb9ddb4641fa3c34a?version=3.37.0) I'm using for a more detailed example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first issue with your code is that you are binding `value` instead of `checked`

```html
<Control title={control.title} bind:value={control.checked} />
```

should be

```html
<Control title={control.title} bind:checked={control.checked} />
```

The second is that your code sets the initial value of the control to *switchTouch* but this is just an assignment, nowhere in your code are you making a link *back* from the control to *switchTouch*.
This can be easily solved using a reactive statement however:

```js
$: switchTouch = controls[0].checked
```

This will update `switchTouch` everytime the *checked* property of the first control changes effectively creating a link between the two variables.

Answer (score 1):

The controls are updated in your code, I believe that you want to see the component changes in your `App.svelte` you can do that by exporting a variable and use `afterUpdate` lifecycle to send the changes. I wrote a small snippet that will be useful check [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/6d960f28c5ad4d04aabda7f2c44969c7?version=3.37.0)